# After adding relation manytomany in my project i can't add new elements into db(to related table)

Tags: sql, jpa, many-to-many, h2

Hello i create project where i have relation manyToMany in ma entity class. After add relation my new table was creatin but when i wanto to add new elements in relation db my project doesn't start.

This is my first relation:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "people")
    private Set<Team> teams = new HashSet<Team>();
```

My second relation:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinTable(name = "persons_teams",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "teamId"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "personId"))
private Set<Person> people = new HashSet<>();
```

But when i add code in sql file :

```
INSERT INTO Persons_Teams(team_id, person_id) VALUES (1,3)
```

program don't compile.
When i delete this sql question program compile and create empty table Person_Teams. How i should add new elements to this relation table ?

This is my error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-05-11 09:56:57.710 ERROR 1272 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personRestController' defined in file [C:\Projekt\crew\crew-core\target\classes\com\softwaremind\crew\people\controller\PersonRestController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file [C:\Projekt\crew\crew-core\target\classes\com\softwaremind\crew\people\service\PersonService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3fdd5219' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3fdd5219': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #5 of URL [file:/C:/Projekt/crew/crew-core/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO Team (id ,name,description,created_on,modified_on) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',parsedatetime('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),null) INSERT INTO Persons_Teams(team_id, person_id) VALUES (1,3) ; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Błąd składniowy w wyrażeniu SQL "INSERT INTO TEAM (ID ,NAME,DESCRIPTION,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_ON) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',PARSEDATETIME('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),NULL) INSERT[*] INTO PERSONS_TEAMS(TEAM_ID, PERSON_ID) VALUES (1,3)  "
Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO TEAM (ID ,NAME,DESCRIPTION,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_ON) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',PARSEDATETIME('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),NULL) INSERT[*] INTO PERSONS_TEAMS(TEAM_ID, PERSON_ID) VALUES (1,3)  "; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Team (id ,name,description,created_on,modified_on) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',parsedatetime('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),null) INSERT INTO Persons_Teams(team_id, person_id) VALUES (1,3)  [42000-197]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.softwaremind.crew.CrewApplication.main(CrewApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file [C:\Projekt\crew\crew-core\target\classes\com\softwaremind\crew\people\service\PersonService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3fdd5219' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3fdd5219': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #5 of URL [file:/C:/Projekt/crew/crew-core/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO Team (id ,name,description,created_on,modified_on) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',parsedatetime('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),null) INSERT INTO Persons_Teams(team_id, person_id) VALUES (1,3) ; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Błąd składniowy w wyrażeniu SQL "INSERT INTO TEAM (ID ,NAME,DESCRIPTION,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_ON) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',PARSEDATETIME('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),NULL) INSERT[*] INTO PERSONS_TEAMS(TEAM_ID, PERSON_ID) VALUES (1,3)  "
Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO TEAM (ID ,NAME,DESCRIPTION,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_ON) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',PARSEDATETIME('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),NULL) INSERT[*] INTO PERSONS_TEAMS(TEAM_ID, PERSON_ID) VALUES (1,3)  "; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Team (id ,name,description,created_on,modified_on) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',parsedatetime('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),null) INSERT INTO Persons_Teams(team_id, person_id) VALUES (1,3)  [42000-197]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3fdd5219' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3fdd5219': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #5 of URL [file:/C:/Projekt/crew/crew-core/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO Team (id ,name,description,created_on,modified_on) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',parsedatetime('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),null) INSERT INTO Persons_Teams(team_id, person_id) VALUES (1,3) ; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Błąd składniowy w wyrażeniu SQL "INSERT INTO TEAM (ID ,NAME,DESCRIPTION,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_ON) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',PARSEDATETIME('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),NULL) INSERT[*] INTO PERSONS_TEAMS(TEAM_ID, PERSON_ID) VALUES (1,3)  "
Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO TEAM (ID ,NAME,DESCRIPTION,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_ON) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',PARSEDATETIME('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),NULL) INSERT[*] INTO PERSONS_TEAMS(TEAM_ID, PERSON_ID) VALUES (1,3)  "; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Team (id ,name,description,created_on,modified_on) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',parsedatetime('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),null) INSERT INTO Persons_Teams(team_id, person_id) VALUES (1,3)  [42000-197]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:327) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:131) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1605) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1357) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3fdd5219': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #5 of URL [file:/C:/Projekt/crew/crew-core/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO Team (id ,name,description,created_on,modified_on) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',parsedatetime('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),null) INSERT INTO Persons_Teams(team_id, person_id) VALUES (1,3) ; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Błąd składniowy w wyrażeniu SQL "INSERT INTO TEAM (ID ,NAME,DESCRIPTION,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_ON) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',PARSEDATETIME('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),NULL) INSERT[*] INTO PERSONS_TEAMS(TEAM_ID, PERSON_ID) VALUES (1,3)  "
Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO TEAM (ID ,NAME,DESCRIPTION,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_ON) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',PARSEDATETIME('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),NULL) INSERT[*] INTO PERSONS_TEAMS(TEAM_ID, PERSON_ID) VALUES (1,3)  "; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Team (id ,name,description,created_on,modified_on) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',parsedatetime('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),null) INSERT INTO Persons_Teams(team_id, person_id) VALUES (1,3)  [42000-197]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:440) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #5 of URL [file:/C:/Projekt/crew/crew-core/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO Team (id ,name,description,created_on,modified_on) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',parsedatetime('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),null) INSERT INTO Persons_Teams(team_id, person_id) VALUES (1,3) ; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Błąd składniowy w wyrażeniu SQL "INSERT INTO TEAM (ID ,NAME,DESCRIPTION,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_ON) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',PARSEDATETIME('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),NULL) INSERT[*] INTO PERSONS_TEAMS(TEAM_ID, PERSON_ID) VALUES (1,3)  "
Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO TEAM (ID ,NAME,DESCRIPTION,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_ON) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',PARSEDATETIME('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),NULL) INSERT[*] INTO PERSONS_TEAMS(TEAM_ID, PERSON_ID) VALUES (1,3)  "; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Team (id ,name,description,created_on,modified_on) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',parsedatetime('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),null) INSERT INTO Persons_Teams(team_id, person_id) VALUES (1,3)  [42000-197]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:114) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1645) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1178) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:257) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #5 of URL [file:/C:/Projekt/crew/crew-core/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO Team (id ,name,description,created_on,modified_on) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',parsedatetime('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),null) INSERT INTO Persons_Teams(team_id, person_id) VALUES (1,3) ; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Błąd składniowy w wyrażeniu SQL "INSERT INTO TEAM (ID ,NAME,DESCRIPTION,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_ON) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',PARSEDATETIME('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),NULL) INSERT[*] INTO PERSONS_TEAMS(TEAM_ID, PERSON_ID) VALUES (1,3)  "
Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO TEAM (ID ,NAME,DESCRIPTION,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_ON) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',PARSEDATETIME('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),NULL) INSERT[*] INTO PERSONS_TEAMS(TEAM_ID, PERSON_ID) VALUES (1,3)  "; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Team (id ,name,description,created_on,modified_on) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',parsedatetime('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),null) INSERT INTO Persons_Teams(team_id, person_id) VALUES (1,3)  [42000-197]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:494) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:240) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:48) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:210) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:93) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:37) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:400) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:354) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:79) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:70) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:437) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1844) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:111) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Błąd składniowy w wyrażeniu SQL "INSERT INTO TEAM (ID ,NAME,DESCRIPTION,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_ON) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',PARSEDATETIME('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),NULL) INSERT[*] INTO PERSONS_TEAMS(TEAM_ID, PERSON_ID) VALUES (1,3)  "
Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO TEAM (ID ,NAME,DESCRIPTION,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_ON) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',PARSEDATETIME('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),NULL) INSERT[*] INTO PERSONS_TEAMS(TEAM_ID, PERSON_ID) VALUES (1,3)  "; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Team (id ,name,description,created_on,modified_on) VALUES (1,'Apacze','grupa programistow',parsedatetime('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'),null) INSERT INTO Persons_Teams(team_id, person_id) VALUES (1,3)  [42000-197]



Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: If i understand you well, you need only one many to many relationship. A direct relationship betweeen  `Persons` and `Teams` does not occur, that's why you need a `Persons_Teams`. (1Person<->∞Person_Teams∞<->1Team)

Comment: Yes i need one relation many to many between persons and teams. If i good understand when i create relation i create automaticly table conntection this both table using primary key. The problem is that when i want to add connected person with team program stop working